# How to print multiple command output in single line batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to print multiple command output in single line batch?

> echo stringProp name="HTTPSamper.xml_dat >> abc.jmx &&  type 
>   abc.txt >> abc.jmx && echo stringProp >>  abc.jmx

I want output of these command to be printed on single line in file abc.jmx
Please help me with this.thanks in advance

Ouput

> stringProp name="HTTPSamper.xml_dat 
>   stringProp

Comment: What did you want to get as result ouput ?

Comment: Closing double quote missing. `>> abc.jmx (echo stringProp name=^"HTTPSamper.xml_dat & type abc.txt & echo stringProp)` or `>> abc.jmx (echo stringProp name="HTTPSamper.xml_dat" & type abc.txt & echo stringProp)` should add multi-line to  the `abc.jmx`. Not much more to say don't knowing the `abc.txt` file contents **and** desired output...

Comment: "I want output of these command to be printed on single line in file abc.jmx" - That requirements seems unlikely to be valid. If ABC.TXT contains multiple lines, than do you really want to eliminate all new lines and have everything appear on one line?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way :

```
@echo off
(
echo stringProp name="HTTPSamper.xml_dat stringProp
)> abc.jmx
::Read Data from abc.jmx
Type abc.jmx
pause
```

Comment: this won't be possible as the action is a part of script

Comment: @ABC In this case post the hole script and explain more your issue and explain this line ==>type abc.txt<== because and don't use it ,as i don't know what came with your script before ?